# Can only create one user profile - Rails 4.2.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, friendly-id

I'm using devise for my user auth and registration. I can register a user no problem. Im also using [friendly](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id). My issue is, I can only create one user profile.

The setup...

**user.rb:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
  validates :name, uniqueness: true, presence: true
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
 has_one :profile # each user should have just one profile
end
```

**profile.rb:**

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
end
```

**profiles_controller.rb:**

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :only_current_user

  def new
    # form where a user can fill out their OWN profile
    @user = User.friendly.find( params[:user_id] )
    @profile = Profile.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.friendly.find( params[:user_id] )
    @profile = @user.build_profile(profile_params)
    if @profile.save # Not saving!!
      flash[:success] = 'Profile Created!'
      redirect_to user_path( params[:user_id] )
    else
      render action: :new # keeps rendering!
    end
  end

  private
    def profile_params
        params.require(:profile).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :avatar,       :job_title, :phone_number, :business_name)
    end
end
```

Why is it that only one user can create a profile and not others? Is it has to do with the relations?

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: no errors. just renders the new action

Comment: If its not saving, there should be an error. Can you post the logs in the question? Also try with `if @profile.save!`

Comment: @Pavan Dude.... what does `save!` do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use this setup with some of our apps -  `User` -> `Profile`.

In short, you should build the profile at User creation. Then you can *edit* the profile as you need. Your problem of having a `Profile.new` method is very inefficient...

---

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :profile 
   before_create :build_profile #-> saves blank associated "Profile" object after user create
end
```

This will mean that each time a `User` is *created*, their corresponding `Profile` object is also appended to the db.

This will give you the capacity to edit the profile as required:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users, path_names: { edit: "profile", update: "profile" }, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
```

This will give you the opportunity to use the following:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:edit, :update]
   before_action :authorize, only: [:edit, :update]

   def show
      @user = User.find params[:id]
   end

   def edit
      @user = current_user
   end

   def update
      @user = current_user
      @user.update user_params
   end

   private

   def authorize
      id = params[:id]
      redirect_to user_show_path(id) if current_user.id != id #-> authorization
   end

   def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:x, :y, :z, profile_attributes: [:homepage, :other, :profile, :attributes])
   end
end
```

The view/form would be the following:

```
#app/views/users/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :profile do |f| %>
       <%= f.text_field :homepage %>
       ...
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

---

In regards your *current* setup:

```
def new
    @profile = current_user.profile.new
end

def create
    @profile = current_user.profile.new profile_params
    if @profile.save
      redirect_to user_path(params[:id]), notice: "Profile Created!"
    else
      render action: :new 
    end
end

private

def profile_params 
   params.require(:profile).permit(:x, :y, :z)
end
```

Comment: I like your user.rb setup. This `before_create :build_profile` makes a huge difference. Thanks.

Comment: @RichardPeck I think this is the solution to a challenge I'm having https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56621887/rails-6-only-one-profile-per-user-can-exit

Comment: So in this case you don't need a profiles controller?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you don't create the profile in the after_create event of the user. As soon the user is created - create an empty (but associated) profile.

```
class User  
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  after_create {
    build_profile unless profile
    profile.save
  }
end

class Profile
  belongs_to :user, autosave: true
end
```

so then, in your controller you just need the update method.

```
def update
  if current_user.profile.update_attributes(user_params)
    flash_it :success
    return redirect_to edit_user_profile_path
  else
    flash_it :error
    render :edit
  end
end
```