# Devise: creating a "profile" using users controller with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm working on a Rails 6 application where I was separating the User and Profile models. This caused some issues as shown in this post [Rails 6: Only one profile per user should be created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56621887/rails-6-only-one-profile-per-user-should-be-created/56622266#56622266)
I'm using Devise for authentication and decided to add a users controller. I want to be able to User the user model as a profile and that Devise takes care of the sign_up, sign_in and the creation of the user.

I created the user's controller to `show`, `edit`, `update` and `destroy` and would use this as the "profile".However, I'm confused about the following. How to make Devise work with the `users_controller` that inherits from `ApplicationRecord` wouldn't this 2 conflict?

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Profile information
      t.string :full_name
      t.string :city
      t.string :bio


      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

I added the other fields into the `DeviseCreateUsers` migration. Should I create a separate `create_users_migration`? I would like for a user to sign up with email and password and not necessarily need the fields `:full_name`,`:city`, `:bio` to create the instance of User.

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
       sessions: 'users/sessions'
     }
  resources :users, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  resources :posts do
    resource :comments, only: %i[show new create edit update]
  end
end
```

When I followed the Devise documentation: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers
I'm a bit confused about the followin. I run the command

```
$ rails generate devise:controllers users
```

[image]

Does the documentation is unclear as to whether one should add the views of `log_in`,`sign_up` those forms into the `users` folder or only `new.html.erb` form `devise/sessions` which is the only template that is generated.

Answer (score -1):

I can't answer your whole question, but I can tell you that you don't need to have all fields filled in to create an instance of user. If you have different fields for sign up and edit form that would work just fine.

Comment: This is not an appropriate post for an answer. Keep in mind the community users' are most likely technical and would expect an answer as such. This would be more appropriate for comment since it doesn't answer the question and is additional information your providing.